# How to stop htaccess redirect replacing URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have the following in my .htaccess file which works fine, except that when I hit:

http://bunkerbuster.com/profiles/1

The URL in the address bar is replaced with the new URL. I don't want this to happen, I want the URL to still show bunkerbuster.com

Thanks for your help.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^profiles/([0-9]+)$ http://projectzebra-bunkerbuster.herokuapp.com/profiles/$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^profiles/([0-9]+)/$ http://projectzebra-bunkerbuster.herokuapp.com/profiles/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you seem to be trying is make Apache act as a proxy.

This can't be done using htaccess but can be done using mod_proxy :

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass